# What exactly is a property procedure?

Tags: vba, excel

I understand that in VBA there are three kinds of procedures:

1. Functions
2. Procedures
3. Property procedures

I searched the web but didn't find a clear definition of property procedures.

Comment: A property procedure is for use with Classes, see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example of a property procedure would be within a custom class module.
It can be retrieved (get) or have its value input (let)

within a custom class (clsExample)

```
Private pName As String
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(value As String)
    pName = value
End Property
```

And you can use one in a standard sub as follows:

```
Sub example()

Dim exampleClass As clsExample
Set exampleClass = New clsExample
exampleClass.Name = "John Smith"
MsgBox (exampleClass.Name)

End Sub
```

Some advantages are that you can give meaningful objects meaningful property names (i.e. project.id, project.manager), and another example is you can give an object derived properties that are read only (only using a get and no set).

Comment: You can actually add properties to *any* module, including standard ones.

Comment: And Forms. They're essentially a Class thenselves

Comment: When you use a property, what is the exact syntax for accessing them, when do you use parentheses?

Comment: Can a property get procedure have parameters?

Comment: Example syntax is already given in the answer. You can use parameters in the get procedure yes.

Answer (score 0):

`Property Procedure` in VBA is called just `Property` in other programming languages (C#, Python).
It is used for [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

The idea of the encapsulation and of the properties, is that you can put some business logic there and it is easy to use.
E.g., lets imagine that you have a truck, which is not allowed to go above 90 km/h. Thus, whenver the driver requires to go with 120, the truck should still go with 90. This is easy to be achieved with properties. The sample is made in `Module1` :

```
Private m_dblSpeed As Double
Private Const MAX_SPEED = 90

Private Property Get dblSpeed() As Double

    dblSpeed = m_dblSpeed

End Property

Private Property Let dblSpeed(ByVal NewValue As Double)

    If NewValue > MAX_SPEED Then
        m_dblSpeed = MAX_SPEED
    Else
        m_dblSpeed = NewValue
    End If

End Property

Public Sub TestModul()

    Modul1.dblSpeed = 120
    Debug.Print Modul1.dblSpeed

    Modul1.dblSpeed = 88
    Debug.Print Modul1.dblSpeed

End Sub
```